# Why is this word "decessor" not a valid entry?

Tags: word-usage

I need to write a handover report and realized this word "decessor" is underlined in red by the word editor, my question is can I still use this word in formal situation and why "predecessor" is acceptable?

Comment: The Latin word meant "retiring or departed officeholder", and [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed03arch#page/n107/mode/2up) gives a couple of instances from the middle of the 17th century, but the word there clearly has the same sense as "predecessor", and it never caught on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot/should not use "decessor."

Contrary to "predecessor," it's not in the Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary, and this says a lot about it being accepted. Equally, it's  [not found at Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22decessor%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a%20decessor%22&tbm=bks&start=0) except in Latin texts, the ones in English being all cases of syllabication of "predecessor."

Not everything that works in Latin has been conveyed/accepted to English:-)